# Как получить экземпляр AndroidViewModel?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Я создал AndroidViewModel для основной активности.Теперь я хочу получить экземпляр AndroidViewModel в основной активности. Для этого я делаю следующее `viewModal = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModal.class);`

Но при запуски, студия выкидывает следующую ошибку

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mymovies, PID: 4377
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mymovies/com.example.mymovies.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.mymovies.data.MainViewModal
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.mymovies.data.MainViewModal
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:221)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:187)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150)
        at com.example.mymovies.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
     Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.example.mymovies.data.MainViewModal> has no zero argument constructor
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:219)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:187) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150) 
        at com.example.mymovies.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Вот код Основной активности

```
package com.example.mymovies;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.mymovies.data.MainViewModal;
import com.example.mymovies.data.Movie;
import com.example.mymovies.utils.JSONUtils;
import com.example.mymovies.utils.NetworkUtils;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Switch switchSort;
    private RecyclerView recyclerViewPosters;
    private MovieAdapter movieAdapter;
    private TextView textViewTopRated;
    private TextView textViewPopularity;

    private MainViewModal viewModal;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        viewModal = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModal.class);


        textViewTopRated = findViewById(R.id.textViewTopRated);
        textViewPopularity = findViewById(R.id.textViewPopularity);
        switchSort = findViewById(R.id.switchSort);
        recyclerViewPosters = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewPosters);
        recyclerViewPosters.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
        movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter();
        recyclerViewPosters.setAdapter(movieAdapter);

        switchSort.setChecked(true);
        switchSort.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                setMethodOfSort(isChecked);
            }
        });
        switchSort.setChecked(false);

        movieAdapter.setOnPosterClickListener(new MovieAdapter.OnPosterClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPosterClick(int position) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        movieAdapter.setOnReachEndListener(new MovieAdapter.OnReachEndListener() {
            @Override
            public void onReachEnd() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Конец списка", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        LiveData<List<Movie>> moviesFromLiveData = viewModal.getMovies();
        moviesFromLiveData.observe(this, new Observer<List<Movie>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Movie> movies) {
                movieAdapter.setMovies(movies);
            }
        });
    }

    public void onClickSetPopularity(View view) {
        setMethodOfSort(false);
        switchSort.setChecked(false);
    }

    public void onClickTopRated(View view) {
        setMethodOfSort(true);
        switchSort.setChecked(true);
    }

    private void setMethodOfSort(boolean isTopRated) {
        int methodOfSort;
        if (isTopRated) {
            textViewTopRated.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
            textViewPopularity.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            methodOfSort = NetworkUtils.TOP_RATED;
        } else {
            textViewTopRated.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            textViewPopularity.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
            methodOfSort = NetworkUtils.POPULARITY;
        }
        downloadData(methodOfSort, 1);
    }

    private void downloadData(int methodOfSort, int page) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = NetworkUtils.getJSONFromNetwork(methodOfSort, page);
        ArrayList<Movie> movies = JSONUtils.getMoviesFromJSON(jsonObject);
        if (movies != null && !movies.isEmpty()) {
            viewModal.deleteAllMovies();
            for (Movie i :
                    movies) {
                viewModal.insertMovie(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

А вот код ViewModel

```
package com.example.mymovies.data;

import android.app.Application;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel;
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class MainViewModal extends AndroidViewModel {

    private static MovieDataBase dataBase;
    private LiveData<List<Movie>> movies;

    public MainViewModal(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);

        dataBase = MovieDataBase.getInstance(getApplication());
        movies = dataBase.movieDao().getAllMovies();
    }

    public Movie getMovieById(int id) {
        try {
            return new GetMovieTask().execute(id).get();
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void deleteAllMovies() {
        new DeleteMovieTask().execute();
    }

    public void deleteMovies(Movie movie) {
        new DeleteTask().execute(movie);
    }

    public void insertMovie(Movie movie) {
        new InsertTask().execute(movie);
    }

    public MainViewModal(@NonNull Application application, LiveData<List<Movie>> movies) {
        super(application);
        this.movies = movies;
    }

    private static class DeleteTask extends AsyncTask<Movie, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Movie... movies) {
            if (movies != null && movies.length > 0) {
                dataBase.movieDao().deleteMovie(movies[0]);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static class InsertTask extends AsyncTask<Movie, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Movie... movies) {
            if (movies != null && movies.length > 0) {
                dataBase.movieDao().insertMovie(movies[0]);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static class DeleteMovieTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            dataBase.movieDao().deleteAllMovies();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static class GetMovieTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Movie> {
        @Override
        protected Movie doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
            if (integers != null && integers.length > 0) {
                return dataBase.movieDao().getMovieById(integers[0]);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public LiveData<List<Movie>> getMovies() {
        return movies;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается в Активности нужно было вместо

`viewModal = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModal.class);`

написать

`viewModel = new ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(getApplication()).create(PostViewModel.class);`